# How protobuf parses a string from a large string?

Tags: proto

I have a message with `repeated field`, assuming the repeating field size is very large, and then I save the proto object to string (`SerializeToString`), which size is 200M.

```
message ChunkBody {
  repeated SingleMessage messages = 1;
}
```

Now If I want to parse this object (`ParseFromString`), I have to read the whole 200M file before I can parse it?

Actually I want to implement the function of iteratively reading repeated messages from file.

---

the environment I want to use

```
lib: protobuf
language : python
```

Comment: Whether you can parse in a streaming fashion is up to the protobuf parsing library in your particular language. You need to specify the language/library that you're using. That said, I haven't heard of a library that supports that. Easiest way is to split your data up into multiple protobuf messages. Like, how is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974718/stream-data-into-protobuf-parser-c

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm limited to "repeated" fields can read separate? Of course, it is also feasible to store a single message separately as an alternative